# podman compose up listens to port 8080

Tags: docker, docker-compose, podman, podman-compose

I have `docker-compose` and `podman-compose` installed on the linux server (RHEL8.6)
I have the docker-compose.yaml file in the directory, which is as shown :

```
version: '3'

services:
  serviceA:
    image: 'AA/XXX:XX.XX.XX'
    ports:
       - "8081:8081"          
    restart: 'always'
    working_dir: /var/serviceA
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Berlin"
    volumes:
      - /var/serviceA:/var/serviceA
      - ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts:/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

I run the `podman-compose up -d`  and see that the container is running. However I cannot access it via `https://localhost:8081`

So when I do a `podman-compose up`, I see that it shows the following log:

```
Listening on http://localhost:8080
```

Why is it that podman does not take the port I specify on the compose file? Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

That `Listening on http://localhost:8080` messages comes from the application running inside the container. Podman takes care of *mapping* a host port to the container port.

If you want to expose the containerized service on host port 8081, you would need to write:

```
services:
  serviceA:
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
```

The syntax of entries in the `ports` list is `<host port>:<container port>`.